# Loop that constantly checks for the requirements

Tags: java

I need to have the Loop not only check at the start if the requirements are fulfilled but also constantly while the programm is running.

I have tried it with this while true and if loop but the: int b = 0; b < 1; b = b + 0; part has errors "Expression expected"

```
while (true) {
    if (int b = 0; b < 1; b = b + 0;) {
        Fetcher FetcherObject = new Fetcher();
        FetcherObject.fetch();
    }
}
```

And this For loop only checks at the launch of the programm.

```
for (b = 0; b < amount; b = b + 0) {
    Fetcher FetcherObject = new Fetcher();
    FetcherObject.fetch();
}
```

This is probably such a noob question sorry.

Comment: This is an error in your `if` statement  `if (int b = 0; b < 1; b = b + 0;)`  It must be `if (boolean_expression)`;  in `for` loop you do no change b and get into endless loop

Comment: Both for and while loops check that their conditions are met every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it a bit and im now using this loop but thanks for all the answers.

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println(runFetcher);
        while (runfetcher) {
            Fetcher FetcherObject = new Fetcher();
            FetcherObject.fetch();
        }
```

Comment: How do you break out of the loop?

Comment: And why don't you use a while loop rather than the for(;;) loop?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: If I understand the inner while loop, it could be simplified to while (runFetcher).

Comment: Also, how do you break out of the loops?

Comment: that works thanks but what do you mean by break out of the loops?

Comment: You have a while (true) loop and a while (runfetcher) loop, and these loops are infinite as I see them.

Comment: Runfetcher is only activated if you press a button but if i just write while (runfetcher) then it only checks if it's true on the start of the program.

Comment: Do i need to break out of a loop performance wise? I thought that i would just close the program.